# Neural networks - simple model

Tags: neural-network

I'm trying to understand an answer to a question on [simple model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLMNI.png).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLMNI.png][1]].

On input we have 2 signals applied on 2 neurons x1 and x2 (look at the image, provided above please). The question is - what will be the output value on y? The answer is y=max(x1,x2). Could you please explain this?

Comment: Your image has text in what I believe is Russian. The question is unanswerable for now.

Comment: thanks for comment! As we see we have two input signals - x1,x2. What signal we get in the end (on y) - hope this would be more clear.

Comment: No, its not clearer because no typical neural network computes max(x1, x2). I cannot relate the given answer to the figure.

Comment: Output of NN actually depends on what you train it to do and not only on the structure of neurons.

Comment: Okey guys it seems I've understand what is happening on this picture. We have two signals, the x1 signal applied to upper Interneuron(with 2 letters inside) making the second(bottom) interneuron to increase it's threshold.

Comment: there are two types of synapses with - and + sign applied on bottom neuron